# Plaid Sandbox Defaults to Plaid Savings and Checkings No Matter What Type of Institution I Link

Tags: plaid

Plaid Sandbox Defaults to Savings and Checkings No Matter What Type of Institution I Link. If I choose a loan or investment account, I should get the right accounts but the api always returns Plaid savings and checkings accounts. What's going on, folks?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is happening because you're initializing with Auth as a product. Auth only supports checking and savings accounts, so including Auth in your product initialization list will limit the available account types to checking and savings.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'investments' in .env file like this, if not already

PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions,**investments**